# Is there a way to disallow other docker containers using the same CPU?

Tags: docker

So it's easy to tell Docker which CPU a container can use:

```
docker run --cpuset=7 some_container_name
```

But this command can be run multiple times and all these processes share the same core.  Is there a way to give a container exclusive access to a CPU and error out if anyone else tries to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a feature of Docker. It would need to be done at a layer above Docker (like Kubernetes or ECS). But it would also be fairly easy to implement this yourself.